# Java - What's the difference between type erasure and type inference?

Tags: java, generics, terminology, type-inference, type-erasure

What's the difference between type erasure and type inference? Are they both compile-time operations?

[**Type Erasure**:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) which removes the generic type information at compile time process.

- Example: `Box<String>` is translated to type `Box`, which is called the raw type.

How [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) is different from type Erasure?
Before JDK 7:

```
Box<String> box=new Box<String>();
```

From JDK 7:

```
 Box<String> box=new Box<>();
```

> My guess the above examples are Type Inference. Is that right?

Is `Type Inference` is opposite to `Type Erasure`?

Comment: Only your second example involves type inference, and of the most trivial kind. It gets far more sophisticated with lambdas in Java 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of them serve completely different needs:

Type erasure is like you said and is needed because java byte code is not generic hence you need to remove the typing. This isn't a feature that helps you code it's just an automatic compile time change that has to happen for the jvm to understand your code.

Type inference on the other hand is the compiler being "smart" and knowing what type you were referring to even though you didn't actually write it. Just like in your example the compiler knows that `Box<>()` actually means `Box<String>()` and lets you continue coding with type safety as if you wrote `Box<String>`. This way you can write less verbose code and the compiler would still understand it.

You can understand from all of this that generics in Java are actually mostly a compile time thing that lets you code with more safety and helps you find errors in compile-time rather than run-time.

Answer (score 4):

They are both compile-time operations.

Type erasure is translation from generic Java source code back into regular Java code (removes `T`, `A` and any other paramterized types).

Type inference can happen when a generic method is invoked or when a generic type object is created. For example, if you

```
class Box<T> {
    ...
}
```

Then when you write

```
Box<String> box = new Box<>();
// type parameter inferred
```

Answer (score 0):

**Key Differences:**

**Focus**: Type erasure is concerned with what happens at compile-time and runtime when generic code is processed, specifically how type information is removed. Type inference is focused on how the compiler determines generic types based on context.

**Purpose**: Type erasure is mainly about backward compatibility and ensuring that generic code can interoperate with non-generic code. Type inference is about improving code readability and reducing the need for explicit type parameter specifications.

**Timing**: Type erasure occurs during the compilation process and affects the generated bytecode. Type inference is a feature of the compiler that determines generic types during the compilation process.